# Why am I getting the wrong List?

Tags: java, list, hashmap, system.out

I am getting some weird results and can't explain them.
Do you have an Idea, why I get

```
> {Level=1 - Normal, Name=IT/Java} 
> {Level=2 - Medium, Name=IT/Ruby}
> [{Level=2 - Medium, Name=IT/Ruby}, {Level=2 - Medium, Name=IT/Ruby}]
```

from the sysos?
when it should actually be

```
> {Level=1 - Normal, Name=IT/Java} 
> {Level=2 - Medium, Name=IT/Ruby}
> [{Level=1 - Normal, Name=IT/Java}, {Level=2 - Medium, Name=IT/Ruby}]
```

Here's my Code.

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> getMapsforTables() {
        levelList = this.getSkilllevel();
        description = this.getSkillnames();
        Map<String, Object> rm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        List<Map<String, Object>> l = new LinkedList<Map<String, Object>>();

        for(int i=0; i < levelList.size(); i++){
            rm.clear();
            rm.put("Name", description.get(i));
            rm.put("Level", levelList.get(i));
            System.out.println(rm);
            l.add(rm);
        }
        System.out.println(l);
        return l;
    }
```

Comment: Please learn what objects and references are - you keep changing an object whilst already placing it in another object and wonder that something changes afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that when you add the element to the `List`:

```
l.add(rm);
```

you are adding a reference to an object.

In the next iteration, you are modifying the object that `rm` refers to, and you add it again. So, you added the same reference twice.

**What can you do?**

A simple solution would be to declare `rm` inside the loop:

```
for(int i=0; i < levelList.size(); i++){
    Map<String, Object> rm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Because on each iteration, you're modifying and adding the same object to the list. You could do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < levelList.size(); i++){
    Map<String, Object> rm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    rm.put("Name", description.get(i));
    rm.put("Level", levelList.get(i));
    System.out.println(rm);
    l.add(rm);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The short version is because you're re-using the same `Map` object over and over again.

Move the `Map<String, Object> rm = new HashMap<String, Object>();` line inside the `for` loop, as the first statement and your issue should go away.

In the longer term, you should look at some general CS or java tutorial on the difference between pass-by-reference and pass-by-value.